# How to draw Arc on canvas on mouse move?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

Can anyone Please tell me how to draw an arc on mouse movement.
I have a compass Image, I want to draw an arc starting from its top. As mouse move it will draw an arc. I can rotate the compass in any direction (from center of compass). Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/qhSd8/)**

The above draws an arc when you click and on mouse move expands it, however it doesnt delete the previous one. Your question is a bit vague, so let me know if this is close to what you were talking about.

Comment: Sir, i have a compass aligned vertically. Now i can rotate this compass on mouse move. So when i rotate the compass it will draw circle or arc starting from its top,left region.